# how to run php laravel artisan commands from web

Tags: php, laravel

How could Laravel Artisan commands be executed on the server by sending the command as a query parameter in an URL?

Answer (score 0):

Without commencing new dockerfile you cant run laravel artisan commands if those need mysql connection command line. If you are searching for quick and dirty hack here it is:

In order to work on existing php-fpm-alpine, use artisan commands from the web interface those code can be added to index.php (generally located in /public directory)

```
if($debugmode)
if(@$_REQUEST['artisan']){
    $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
    $vars = explode(' ', $_REQUEST['artisan']);
    $status = $kernel->handle(
        $input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($vars),
        new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput
    );

        return  '';
}
```

those shoud come between

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

and

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

usage `http://localhost/?artisan=vendor:publish`

Comment: This is potentially *very* dangerous code to have in your app.

Comment: You do have a check for `if($debugmode)`, so as long as that's disabled in a `production` environment, this isn't too bad. But exposing `artisan` commands to anyone who could just edit their URL opens up some fun applications. For example, run `http://localhost/?artisan=key:generate` to generate a new app key and destroy existing hashes/encryption/etc. Or even better, `http://localhost/?artisan=migrate:reset`; there goes all your database tables/rows.